# Spring authorization server behind spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-authorization-server

For my learning purpose I have created a spring authorization server application, spring cloud gateway where I have configured PKCE for my react app  , if react app connects directly with authorization server i am getting token but if i change the endpoint via gateway its takes me to login and after that 404 error my gateway config is below (i am using consul for service discovery)

`spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=authServer spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://auth-server spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/auth/** spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[0]=RewritePath=/auth/(?<segment>.*),/$\{segment}`

and on spring authorization server end i have created a bean of ClientRpository like below

```
@Bean
public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
    RegisteredClient publicClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .clientId("web-client")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:3000")
            .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
            .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder()
                    .requireAuthorizationConsent(false)
                    .requireProofKey(true)
                    .build()
            )
            .build();

    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(publicClient);
}
```

I want to ask if there are any changes needed in security config of authorization server or spring authorization server.

https://github.com/haiderali22/springboot-oauth2 link of the github repo

Edit:

See the paste bin link for logs https://pastebin.com/4b5Q9Ly7

And my cors configuration is

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new 

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
        config.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://127.0.0.1:3000");

        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
```

Comment: Please share the trace logs from the authorization server, enabled via `logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace`.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg added the logs i thinks its happening because of my cors configuration  thats why direct call is working and not through gateway, i tried disabling the cors but its throwing cors error on token endpoint

Comment: It is possible you will need to configure CORS on the gateway. I took a look at the logs, and they don't seem to show any requests related to OAuth2. I see a request to `/login` followed by a request to `/`, both are successful. Since I don't see anything in the Spring Security logs that point to an error, you must be getting an error through something that isn't logging anything.

Comment: i tried disabling the cors on authorization server but its  was throwing cors error on token endpoint, i will recheck it tomorrow maybe some configuration issue

Comment: Just realized the request to `/` is what's causing your 404 error, since you clearly do not have a controller for that endpoint. Why/how is your client getting to the `/login` page?

Comment: i am using react-oauth2-code-pkce lib in react application which is redirecting the app to login, If i use the authorization server url its working fine but not through gateway (which is probably because of cors)

Comment: Ok, I see. Then yes it seems likely a CORS issue. Are you seeing CORS errors in the browser's dev tools console?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg my current finding is i was calling localhost:8080/auth/oauth2/authorize (through gateway) from react app using localhost but gateway(consul load balancing) was sending request to oauth server using my wlan ip i.e. 192.168.1.5:8081/oauth2/authorize, when i used my wlan ip when request from client(react app) now application is able to  get token